# Streamout print statements of a function

Tags: python, function

I have a function with plenty of print statements inside. I call that function in my code passing the required arguments. Now, I want to capture the print statements of that called function to a list while those print statements are getting printed on the screen. Not a pure redirection.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to re-invent the `logging` module... In the early times, programmers used to clutter their code with print statements for debugging, and removed them in production code. Then people realized that is deserved a real framework to be able to easily *activate* traces at a fine grained level, and they invented *logging*. The standard library `logging` module is a nice implementation of this concept and it probably meets your real requirements (and possibly more...). Unsure anyway if it really answers your question, hence a mere comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to redefine the print function

```py
import builtins

texts = []
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    builtins.print(*args, **kwargs)
    texts.append(str(*args))
```

Here we use the package `builtins` to access the origin function and we define a new `print` function.
This will result in your function to call this new defined `print` and add all the printed texts to the `texts` list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Redefining print function to gather in a list will be the right approach.